# How to make unfocused window acrylic?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp

When the acrylic window is unfocused it isn't acrylic.

Code

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="AcrilicTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:media="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Media"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <media:AcrylicBrush x:Key="HostBackdropBrush"
                            BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                            TintColor="LightBlue"
                            TintOpacity="0.6"
                            FallbackColor="LightSkyBlue" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource HostBackdropBrush}" />
</Page>
```

---

Screenshots

Focused (acrylic):

[image]

Unfocused (not acrylic):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's by design. 'Rendering acrylic surfaces is GPU-intensive, which can increase device power consumption and shorten battery life.' When an app window on desktop deactivates, background acrylic will be replaced with a solid color. See [Acrylic material](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic#usability-and-adaptability) for more details.

> Can I disable this feature for a beautiful interface?

If you use the background acrylic(`BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"`), it's impossible. If you use in-app acrylic(`BackgroundSource="Backdrop"`), in your case, it will look more better. When your app isn’t in the active desktop window, the acrylic is still there.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush"
        BackgroundSource="Backdrop"
        TintOpacity="0.3" TintColor="#FFFF0000" FallbackColor="#FF008000"></AcrylicBrush>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/panda.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    </Grid.Background>

    <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource MyAcrylicBrush}" Height="300" Width="500"></Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Can I disable this feature for a beautiful interface? I saw an app (terminus, maybe on an electron), that always acrylic.

Comment: If I use this brush on Page it's acrylic but in a white background (not normal acrylic). ```<Page.Background>
        <AcrylicBrush
        BackgroundSource="Backdrop"
        TintOpacity="0.3" TintColor="#FFFF0000" FallbackColor="#FF008000"></AcrylicBrush>
    </Page.Background>```

Comment: @Wootiae No. You did misunderstand my meaning. The in-app acrylic is not for this scenario. You need to understand [in-app acrylic and background acrylic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic#when-to-use-acrylic). In a word, if you want to make your window's background always keep acrylic effect no matter if it's focused/unfocused, it's impossible.

Comment: What I let you use the in-app acrylic is a workaround, it will keep the child UI elements with acrylic effect in most of the time.

Comment: It's not impossible - the Notepads app is a UWP app that somehow shows acrylic when not focused: https://www.notepadsapp.com/